# Best way to follow a log and execute a command when some text appears in the log

Tags: text-processing, shell-script, logs, tail

I have a server log that outputs a specific line of text into its log file when the server is up. I want to execute a command once the server is up, and hence do something like the following:

```
tail -f /path/to/serverLog | grep "server is up" ...(now, e.g., wget on server)?
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: be sure to use `tail -F` to handle log rotation - i.e. `my.log` becomes full and moves to `my.log.1` and your process creates a new `my.log`

Comment: Here's a related discussion in the Ubuntu Q&A site: https://askubuntu.com/q/1052891/31592

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A simple way would be awk.

```
tail -f /path/to/serverLog | awk '
                    /Printer is on fire!/ { system("shutdown -h now") }
                    /new USB high speed/  { system("echo \"New USB\" | mail admin") }'
```

And yes, both of those are real messages from a kernel log.  Perl might be a little more elegant to use for this and can also replace the need for tail.  If using perl, it will look something like this:

```
open(my $fd, "<", "/path/to/serverLog") or die "Can't open log";
while(1) {
    if(eof $fd) {
        sleep 1;
        $fd->clearerr;
        next;
    }
    my $line = <$fd>;
    chomp($line);
    if($line =~ /Printer is on fire!/) {
        system("shutdown -h now");
    } elsif($line =~ /new USB high speed/) {
        system("echo \"New USB\" | mail admin");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the `awk` solution for being short and easy to do on the fly in one line. However, if the command I want to run has quotes, this can be a bit cumbersome, is there an alternative, maybe using pipelines and compound commands that also allows a brief one-liner solution but doesn't require the resulting command to be passed as a string?

Comment: @jon You can write awk as a script.  Use "#!/usr/bin awk -f" as the first line of the script.  This will eliminate the need for the outer single quotes in my example and free them for use inside a `system()` command.

Comment: @penguin359, True, but it'd still be interesting to do it from the command line as well. In my case, there are a variety of different things I'd want to do including many things I can't foresee, so it's convenient to be able to just start the server and do it all in one line.

Comment: I found an alternative, though I don't know how solid it is: `tail -f /path/to/serverLog | grep "server is up" | head -1 && do_some_command`

Comment: @jon  That seems a little fragile using head that way.  More importantly, it's not repeatable like my examples.  If "server is up" is in the last ten lines of the log, it will fire the command and exit immediately.  If you restart it, it will most likely fire and exit again unless ten lines not containing "server is "up have been added to the log.  A modification of that that might work better is `tail -n 0 -f /path/to/serverLog`  That will read the last 0 lines of the file, then wait for more lines to print.

Comment: However, if your goal is to fire a command every single time something appears in the log files, both version of tail and head may miss lines between each invocation.

Comment: Thanks, -n 0 will help. In my current case, a little fragility isn't an issue because I'm just going through experimental iteration. From another question, I found that `grep -m 1 "server is up" <(tail -n 0 -f /path/to/serverLog); some_command` avoids problems with a pipe remaining alive when I expect it to die and have the command terminate.

Comment: @jon  You may stil want `&&` instead of `;`.  The `&&` means execute the next command if and only if the previous command was successful.  The `;` means execute the second command when the first command finishes.  For example, if I hit Ctrl-Z I get a funny behavior and the second command executes immediately.  With `&&` this doesn't happen.

Comment: Syntaxe `tail -f ... | perl -ne ...` may present same simple syntax than using `... | awk ...`. The most important part of your script is `tail-into-perl`.

Comment: Use `tail -F` (capital f) to account for rotating logs. i.e. `my.log` becomes full and moves to `my.log.1` and your process creates a new `my.log`

Answer (score 31):

If you're only looking for one possibility and want to stay mostly in the shell rather than using `awk` or `perl`, you could do something like:

```
tail -F /path/to/serverLog | 
grep --line-buffered 'server is up' | 
while read ; do my_command ; done
```

...which will run `my_command` every time "*server is up*" appears in the log file.  For multiple possibilities, you could maybe drop the `grep` and instead use a `case` within the `while`.

The capital `-F` tells `tail` to watch for the log file to be rotated; *i.e.* if the current file gets renamed and another file with the same name takes its place, `tail` will switch over to the new file.

The `--line-buffered` option tells `grep` to flush its buffer after every line; otherwise, `my_command` may not be reached in a timely fashion (assuming the logs have reasonably sized lines).

Comment: I really like this answer, but it didn't work for me at first. I think you need to add the `--line-buffered` option to `grep`, or otherwise make sure it flushes its output between lines: otherwise, it just hangs, and `my_command` is never reached.

If you prefer `ack`, it has a `--flush` flag; if you prefer `ag`, try wrapping with `stdbuf`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982518/what-is-ags-silver-searcher-analogous-option-to-greps-line-buffered

Comment: I tried this, using `do exit ;`. It seemed to work fine, but tail never finished and our script never moved onto the next line.  Is there a way to stop tail in the `do` section?

Comment: If you need the log line in `my_command`, you can use `... while read line; do my_command $line ; done`

Comment: add `-n0` to the tail command to ensure it doesn't read any previous lines, ie, after a restart, or conversely `-n +0` to ensure it reads from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 15):

It is strange that no one mentioned about `multitail` utility which has this functionality out-of-box. One of usage example:

> Show the output of a ping-command and if it displays a timeout, send a message to all users currently logged in

```
multitail -ex timeout "echo timeout | wall" -l "ping 192.168.0.1"
```

See also [another examples](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.html) of `multitail` usage.

Comment: +1, I had no idea `multitail had those kind of ninja skills tucked away. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 14):

This question appears to be answered already, but I think there's a better solution.

Rather than `tail | whatever`, I think what you really want is `swatch`. Swatch is a program designed explicitly for doing what you're asking, watching a log file and executing actions based on log lines. Using `tail|foo` will require that you've got a terminal actively running to do this. Swatch on the other hand runs as a daemon and will always be watching your logs. Swatch is available in all Linux distros,

I encourage you to try it out. While you can pound a nail in with the back side of a screwdriver does not mean you should.

The best 30-second tutorial on swatch I could find is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140922041805/http://campin.net/newlogcheck.html).

Comment: That tutorial is 404 now :/

Comment: WebArchive is your friend: http://web.archive.org/web/20140922041805/http://campin.net/newlogcheck.html

Answer (score 8):

#### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) could do the job by himself

Let see how simple and readable it could be:

```
mylog() {
    echo >>/path/to/myscriptLog "$@"
}

while read line;do
    case "$line" in
        *"Printer on fire"* )
            mylog Halting immediately
            shutdown -h now
            ;;
        *DHCPREQUEST* )
            [[ "$line" =~ DHCPREQUEST\ for\ ([^\ ]*)\  ]]
            mylog Incomming or refresh for ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            $HOME/SomethingWithNewClient ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            ;;
        * )
            mylog "untrapped entry: $line"
            ;;
    esac
  done < <(tail -f /path/to/logfile)
```

While you don't use bash's `regex`, this could stay very quick!

#### But [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) + [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is a very efficient and interesting tandem

But for high load server, and as I like `sed` because it's very quick and very scalable, I often use this:

```
while read event target lost ; do
    case $event in
        NEW )
            ip2int $target intTarget
            ((count[intTarget]++))
        ...

    esac
done < <(tail -f /path/logfile | sed -une '
  s/^.*New incom.*from ip \([0-9.]\+\) .*$/NEW \1/p;
  s/^.*Auth.*ip \([0-9.]\+\) failed./FAIL \1/p;
  ...
')
```

Answer (score 6):

That's how i started doing this too but have become much more sophisticated with it. A couple things to be concerned with:

1. If the tail of the log already contains "server is up".
2. Automatically ending the tail process once it's found.

---

I use something along the lines of this:

```
RELEASE=/tmp/${RANDOM}$$
(
  trap 'false' 1
  trap "rm -f ${RELEASE}" 0
  while ! [ -s ${RELEASE} ]; do sleep 3; done
  # You can put code here if you want to do something
  # once the grep succeeds.
) & wait_pid=$!
tail --pid=${wait_pid} -F /path/to/serverLog \
| sed "1,10d" \
| grep "server is up" > ${RELEASE}
```

It works by holding `tail` open until the `${RELEASE}` file contains data.

Once the `grep` succeeds it:

1. writes the output to `${RELEASE}` which will
2. terminate the `${wait_pid}` process to
3. exit the `tail`

Note: The `sed` can be more sophisticated to actually determine the number of lines `tail` will produce at startup and the remove that number. But generally, it's 10.

Comment: You could instead add the option `-n 0` to tail instead of having the `sed`

Comment: Also, it seems you need the `--line-buffered` option on `grep` to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I use fail2ban to monitor and execute a command

Comment: Perhaps a small example would benefit the OP & others? The question starts with: *tail -f /path/to/serverLog | grep "server is up"* ... and then execute a command.