# Tail a log and execute command when message stops

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to write a script that will tail a log and look for a specific message.  When the message appears, the script needs to continue to monitor the log, and when the message has not appeared again for 5 seconds, I need the script to execute a command.

Here's the pseudo code:

tailing log file
Found message "an error occurred"
The message repeats anywhere from 10 to 20 times.
Once the message has stopped scrolling, wait 5 seconds and execute "systemctl restart myservice"

I was trying to use awk, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to wait until the message stops scrolling before I execute the command.  Here's the code I had:

```
tail -F /var/log/mylog.log | awk '
                    /TestString goes here/ { system("sleep 5; systemctl restart myservice") }'
```

Comment: Someone else asked this exact question about 6 months ago on stackoverflow. Search the archives there.

Comment: [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12075/17666)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `bash`, corutils `timeout` and an intermediary file:

*restart-server.bash*

```bsh
# Wait for the initial "TestString"
tail -n0 -F logfile |
while IFS= read -r; do 
  if [[ "$REPLY" == TestString ]]; then 
    break
  fi
done

# See if "TestString" repeats at least every 5 seconds
touch ts
while [ -e ts ]; do
  rm -f ts
  timeout 5 bash -c '
tail -n0 -f logfile |
while IFS= read -r; do 
  if [[ "$REPLY" == TestString ]]; then 
    touch ts
  fi
done
'
done

systemctl restart myserver
```

See [Greg's wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more on bash while-read loops.

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks!